# Array list method in driver class not functioning

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, methods

Okay, so I have a class where I have a method which uses an Arraylist but I'm not sure how to test it in my driver class.

Thanks for any help that you can give me

In my driver class I have this written out but it doesn't work:

```
otherClass test = new otherClass();
test.showLists(theArraylist);
```

Here's my method from my class:

```
public static void showLists(ArrayList list){ 
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you are having?

Comment: Why is this tagged driver?

Comment: what is the value of `theArraylist` in the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

Since you defined your method in "otherClass" as static, you can simply call it as `otherClass.showLists(theArrayList);` without initializing an object of otherClass. Read more about static methods [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).
Alternately, you can remove the static keyword from your showLists method and keep the driver code as-is.

Also, you should make it a practice to start your classnames with uppercase as per Java convention.

Comment: It says that the arraylist cannot be resolved to a variable. The arraylist already has stuff in it from the other class, what should I do about this?

Comment: Was the issue calling a static method from an instance?  I'm sure is should let you do that even of it isn't a good idea.

Comment: @Bajal How do I call a specific arraylist from the other class?

Comment: I don't follow. Can you add the code for both the classes in your original question? There seems to be something structurally wrong in how you have written the classes.